# Cant set hostname on Linode Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

We are trying to deploy our Rails app using Passenger and Nginx on a Linode Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid box.

We cant seem to set the hostname from the root IPv6 address of our Ubuntu box.

We get the error:

```
root@`ourIPv6`:~# hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
```

when i type in `hostname` it returns `myhost`
however when I type in `hostname -f` it returns `hostname: Name or service not known`

What would be the necessary action to take to set the hostname?

```
hosts file:
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1 localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1 localhost
    fe80::1%lo0 localhost

    97.107.128.97 plato.example.com   plato
```

Comment: To set the hostname, just run `hostname new_hostname`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ok. we will try that. were following this [Linode Getting Started Guide](http://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_set-the-hostname). just trying to deploy

Comment: Run the command listed in the guide. It should work.

Comment: Can you be any more specific? It works for me.

Comment: see the above edit, let me know if that is any clarification. this is our first rodeo trying to deploy with passenger, nginx, on the ubuntu 10.04, were having difficulty understanding how it all fits together

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7924/discussion-between-scud-bomb-and-blender)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` and make sure that the hostname you want is in your hosts file there and then do `#: hostname -F /etc/hostname`.

Comment: we did that, im going to add to the contents of the host file to the actual question above. we went to the etc directory and there is no `hostname` file, only `hosts`. just to clarify, this is the etc file on the computer im deploying from, right? or is it on the ubuntu box from linode?

Comment: On the linode box.  Doing it on your computer would make no difference.

Comment: ok. how do we edit files on the box? via terminal? i dont understand that

Comment: we've been following the [linode getting started guide](http://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_set-the-hostname) as noted above. having a tough time completing.

Comment: I'm in chat now. But I'll post this here too.  Yes, you need to SSH to the terminal of the linode machine. After you do that you can run the commands such as:

    echo "plato" > /etc/hostname
    hostname -F /etc/hostname

I'm unsure as to what changing the hostname actually does for you though, it's only local to the machine.